# Condition statement in value attr CGridView Yii

Tags: php, yii, conditional-statements, cgridview

when I do this in CgridView:

```
'value' => '$data->status == 1 ? "Payed" : "None" ',
```

it works, but when I do this:

```
'value' => 'if ($data->status == 1) { echo "Payed"; } else if($data->status == 2) { echo "Two"; } else { echo "None"; } '.
```

What I need to do to make work the second statement, or how I need to rewrite it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your statement to use ternary if:

```
'value' => '$data->status == 1 ? "Payed": ($data->status == 2 ? "Two" : "None")',
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a function instead to give a bit more flexibility and make it more readable:

```
'value' => function($row, $data ) {
    if ($data->status == 1) { return "Payed"; } 
    else if($data->status == 2) { return "Two"; }
    else { return "None"; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case :

I've tried topher's solution and I found out that I had to switch param like that :

```
'value' => function($data, $row ) {
    if ($data->status == 1) { return "Payed"; } 
    else if($data->status == 2) { return "Two"; }
    else { return "None"; }
}
```

With topher's solution `$data->attribute_name` did not work and was, in fact, the row instead of the model..

Perhaps, if you don't need $row, don't pass it.

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
function checkStatus($status)
{
    if ($status == 1) {
        return "opl";
    } else if ($status == 2) {
        return "nal";
    } else {
        return "neopl";
    }
}

'value' => 'checkStatus($data->status)',
```

But your will work too) I will accept answer)

Comment: I would use an anonymous function like topher. Normal functions aren't the `Yii-way`